# cross validation for split test and train datasets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Unlike standart data, I have dataset contain separetly as train, test1 and test2.  I implemented ML algorithms and got performance metrics. But when i apply cross validation, it's getting complicated.. May be someone help me.. Thank you..

It's my code..

```
train = pd.read_csv('train-alldata.csv',sep=";")
test = pd.read_csv('test1-alldata.csv',sep=";")
test2 = pd.read_csv('test2-alldata.csv',sep=";")

X_train = train_pca_son.drop('churn_yn',axis=1)
y_train = train_pca_son['churn_yn']

X_test = test_pca_son.drop('churn_yn',axis=1)
y_test = test_pca_son['churn_yn']

X_test_2 = test2_pca_son.drop('churn_yn',axis=1)
y_test_2 = test2_pca_son['churn_yn']
```

For example, KNN Classifier.

```
knn_classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors =7,metric='euclidean')
knn_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

For K-Fold.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score


dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)

k_folds = KFold(n_splits = 5)

scores = cross_val_score(dtc, X, y, cv = k_folds)

print("Cross Validation Scores: ", scores)
print("Average CV Score: ", scores.mean())
print("Number of CV Scores used in Average: ", len(scores))
```

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. *Cross-validation is a resampling method that uses different portions of the data to test and train a model on different iterations.* You can use your test data as test set to test your model after it has been cross-validated.

Comment: It depends on the task defined; You can merge both test sets or report the results for each one separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation on the "*holdout test data*" pattern (see also: [Wikipedia: Training, Validation, Test / Confusion in terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_data_sets#Confusion_in_terminology)). For churn prediction: this may arise if you have two types of customers, or are evaluating on two time frames.

```
X_train, y_train    ← perform training and hyperparameter tuning with this
X_test1, y_test1    ← test on this
X_test2, y_test2    ← test on this as well
```

Cross validation estimates holdout error using the training data—it may come up if you estimate hyperparameters with [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). Final evaluation involves estimating performance on two test sets, separately or averaged over the two:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.4)
X_test1, X_test2, y_test1, y_test2 = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=.5)

print(y_train.shape, y_test1.shape, y_test2.shape)
# (600,) (200,) (200,)

clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=7).fit(X_train, y_train)

print(f1_score(y_test1, clf.predict(X_test1)))
print(f1_score(y_test2, clf.predict(X_test2)))
# 0.819
# 0.805
```